# Find the limit of $\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{k}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find the limit of

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{k}\right)\qquad \theta>0$$
as $n\to \infty$. I know that since $x-\frac{x^3}{6}\leq \sin x \leq x$ then

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\sin \left( \frac{\theta}{k}\right)\leq \frac{\theta}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k=\theta\frac{(n+1)}{2n}$$

Since the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\theta\frac{(n+1)}{2n}=\frac\theta2$, then we know that

$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\sin \left( \frac{\theta}{k}\right)\leq \frac \theta2 \qquad n \to \infty$$

Now I concentrate on the other side and, with the same logic, I obtain

$$\frac{\theta}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk -\frac{\theta^3}{6n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\leq\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\sin \left( \frac{\theta}{k}\right)$$

How to prove that also the left side tends to $\frac\theta2$? Can you give me a little hint please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$\frac{\theta}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k = \theta\frac{n+1}{2n}= \frac{\theta}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
while:
$$\frac{\theta^3}{6n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{\theta^3}{6}\cdot\frac{H_n}{n^2}=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),$$
since, obviously:
$$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1 = n.$$

Comment: Since I am new to this big Oh notation, I know only the basic definition. Do you mind if I ask you to explain briefly how you transformed my notation in this new way? Would you also provide me some reference about it? I discovered this notation in chapter 8 of my Apostol.

Comment: You wrote that $$\frac{\theta^3}{6} \frac{H_n}{n^2}=O\left( \frac 1n \right)$$ because you can ignore the multiplicative constant. Then you know that the harmonic partial sum is lower than 1. Finally, since $$\frac{1}{n^2}=O\left(\frac 1n \right)$$ you conclude that the whole right side is $$O\left(\frac 1n \right)$$ Am I right?

Comment: Quite. Since $H_n=O(n)$, then $\frac{H_n}{n^2}=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: Ok, so you used $H_n=O(n)$,  $1/n^2=O(1/n^2)$ and the product rule for big Oh notation. Am I right now?